# How is the length of the message counted when calling eth_sign?

Tags: json-rpc, signature

According to https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sign

> The sign method calculates an Ethereum specific signature with:
>
> ```
> sign(keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + len(message) + message)))
> ```

It does not, however, specify how the `len` function works.  If you give it a string containing emojis and zero width joiners, for example, how is the length calculated?  Is it a count of code points, code units, graphemes or glyphs? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27331885/879046)

Answer (score 2):

`message` is actually just a byte array.  The prefix string only contains ASCII-7 characters, so it doesn't really matter how you encode it because ASCII-7, ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16, etc. will all encode it the same.  You then take the encoded bytes of that and append the message length (which is just a byte array, so a simple .length will work) and turn that number into a string and encode it just like the prefix.  Then append the bytes that make up the message on the end.

The code referenced code snippet makes it look like `message` is a string but it is just pseudocode and probably won't actually compile unless your language does implicit casting of strings to arrays.